# How to Join 2 panda dataframe and add a denoting column of respective dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 2 dataframes

1. Fake News
2. Real News

And they both have similar columns like title, subject, text, date

Now I Want to add these two dataframes into one and add an additional column

`Validity` whose value will be `1` if it is real news and `0` if it is fake news

Comment: Can you please post the heads of the dataframes and the expected output?

Comment: thankyou it worked

Comment: You could get *fancy* with the keys argument of `pd.concat` but seems most simple to assign the `'Validity'` column before you join them?

Comment: You are right !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have 2 following source DataFrames:

1. *real_df*:

   ```
             title         subject         text        date
   0  Real_title_1  Real_subject_1  Real_text_1  2020-03-01
   1  Real_title_2  Real_subject_2  Real_text_2  2020-03-03
   ```
2. *fake_df*:

   ```
             title         subject         text        date
   0  Fake_title_1  Fake_subject_1  Fake_text_1  2020-03-04
   1  Fake_title_2  Fake_subject_2  Fake_text_2  2020-03-06
   ```

To concatenate them with "labels of origin" you can use:

```
df = pd.concat([real_df, fake_df], keys=[1, 0])
```

The result (for now) is:

```
            title         subject         text        date
1 0  Real_title_1  Real_subject_1  Real_text_1  2020-03-01
  1  Real_title_2  Real_subject_2  Real_text_2  2020-03-03
0 0  Fake_title_1  Fake_subject_1  Fake_text_1  2020-03-04
  1  Fake_title_2  Fake_subject_2  Fake_text_2  2020-03-06
```

where the labels of origin are in the top level of the multiindex.

To turn it into a "regular" column and give it the desired name, run:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Validity'})
```

Now the result is as you wish, namely:

```
   Validity         title         subject         text        date
0         1  Real_title_1  Real_subject_1  Real_text_1  2020-03-01
1         1  Real_title_2  Real_subject_2  Real_text_2  2020-03-03
2         0  Fake_title_1  Fake_subject_1  Fake_text_1  2020-03-04
3         0  Fake_title_2  Fake_subject_2  Fake_text_2  2020-03-06
```